# documnt.addEventListener leads to "Uncaught TypeError 'Property handleEvent' is not callable."

Tags: dom, firefox, addeventlistener

I have a simple HTML file, which loads the script `"asyncLoader.js"`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="de" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src     = "js/dom/asyncLoader.js" async></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Test</h1>
    </body>

</html>
```

The file `"js/dom/asyncLoader.js"` looks like this:

```
function doSomething() {
    function helper() {
        console.log("DOM is loaded now.");
    }
    helper();
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", new doSomething);
```

Runnig this, it produces "DOM is loaded now." as expected, but then I get the error in Firefox:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'handleEvent' is not callable.
```

Any idea what this error means and how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

This has solved the problem for me:

I changed

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", new doSomething);
```

to

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", doSomething);
```